# Widening operator CType for COM Interop

Tags: vb.net, vbscript, com, vb6

I am having a strange issue with my code. I have a .NET code that i need to make available for COM interoperability. I have done the needful so all my properties and methods are exposed as COM objects in the VB script.

But there is a small thing that I need to be able to do. Let me explain by posting a snippet of the code

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On
Class X

Public text as string
Public index as integer

Public Shared Widening Operator CType(ByVal i As X) As String
        Return i.Text
End Operator

End Class
```

In this code, I have properties to set/get the Text and Index members of the class. But in my script (which were written long back when .NET was not in picture), there is a function called "Display" which takes a string and displays it in a textbox.
I even tried Option Explicit Off to ensure that implicit conversions work.

This Display needs to use the method like below.

Display X (This should by default to X.Text and display it on  the screen)

All this works well if I am using the dll in another .NET project but throws an error "No such property or method"

Any help will be appreciated. If you need any other info also please feel free to ask. This is becoming a showstopper for us.

Comment: Conversion operators is a feature of the VB.NET language, only the compiler knows about it and only the compiler knows when it needs to be called.  It cannot work in any runtime environment beyond that, certainly not in a scripting language.  The intended usage is very unclear to me but it sounds like you'll need to add an explicit Display() method or property.

Answer (score 0):

For COM, you should declare your default property with the `<DispId(0)>` attribute.  [DISPID 0 is the default or value member](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221306%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Alternatively, you may have a separate method or property with DISPID 0 that's not part of any interface you're implementing, in case `.Text` must have a non-zero DISPID.